# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public accessible

Tags: java

I'm having issues processing an API JSON response in a JavaFX app. I get the error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public com.democompany.app.api.ResponseToken() accessible: module com.democompany.app does not "exports com.democompany.app.api" to module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
```

The code:

```
String responseString = responseBody.string();                
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
ResponseToken responseToken = objectMapper.readValue(responseString, ResponseToken.class);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the solution is already given in the error message: export the package to the module. To do so, add a line

```
exports com.democompany.app.api to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
```

to your `module-info.java` file.

Have a look [here](https://openjdk.org/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) for more details – but this is *really* just the starting point.